# How to set up read permissions for anything inside a filemount and write permissions for selected subfolders?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x

I would like to set up backend user accounts for translators with restricted file permissions. They may read all files from the global fileadmin/media/ filemount but may not changes anything. For each user there should be a selected subfolder with write permissions, e.g. fileadmin/media/translation/es/

The only way to set up such permissions I found is via [TSconfig](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/Administration/Permissions.html#fal-administration-permissions-user) and refers to file-storages.

Is there no way to set it by just using mountpoints, and if not, where should an additional storage point to? Also fileadmin/ or do I need to create something like fileadmin-es/ ?

Comment: What is about settings in usergroups and backend accounts, there you also can use mountpoints?

Comment: Yes, but I haven't found a way to assign different file permissions to mountpoints.

Comment: whats about creating the same mountpoints twice, once with read permission, once with write permission?

Comment: Would love to, but I don't know how to set different permissions to two mountpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a read-only option for mountpoints, that allows to assign restricted (read-only) access to files:

[image]

You need three Mountpoints:

One for users without restrictions:

- /fileadmin/media/

Two for users with restrictions:

- /fileadmin/media/ [read-only]
- /fileadmin/media/translation/es/